# Weighted mean and error propagation, again

Tags: variance, mean, uncertainty

I was trying to implement the method proposed by @whuber in this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/454120/how-can-i-calculate-uncertainty-of-the-mean-of-a-set-of-samples-with-different-u#comment844099_454266) to average some of my data. For example:
$62.7\pm 6.8$

$65.3\pm 0.94$

$66.5 \pm 6.0$

$71.8 \pm 7.8$

So far, I have two concerns:

1. The data and uncertainty are not from direct measurements, but from data fitting, i.e., the uncertainty is usually given by the square root of the covariance matrix in chi2 minimization or some credible levels in MCMC sampling. Does this method still work in such a case? Because I notice that it assumes the $\sigma_i$ are accurately known.
2. Applying the method to the above samples, I always get $\hat\sigma_{j} = 0$ in each step of the iteration. Does that mean the original uncertainty is big enough for determining the uncertainty of the weighted average?

PS: Since I am not so familiar with statistics, what would be the best way to cite it if I want to use this method in one of my research papers?

Comment: The issue might be due to the tiny SD of the second value.  However, I can't reproduce your problem.  I ran the code in the referenced answer after changing the inputs to `x <- c(62.7, 65.3, 66.5, 71.8); sigma.i <- c(6.8, 0.94, 6.0, 7.8)`  It produced a warning message about the iterations (a situation anticipated in the arguments to `var.wt`) and fixed simply by using `var.wt(x, sigma.i, iter.max=1e3)` in the bootstrap iterations. The results look fine. The output is a 95% bootstrap interval from 62.93 to 67.86.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comments! Actually, I mean before the parametric bootstrap, when I was running 'x <- c(62.7, 65.3, 66.5, 71.8);sigma.i <- c(6.8, 0.94, 6.0, 7.8);(s <- var.wt(x, sigma.i))'. The iteration lasts for two steps which are both 0 and stops. And in most cases of the parametric bootstrap, the weighted SD equals 0 as well. Is it okay to say the original uncertainty is big enough for determining the uncertainty of the weighted average?

Comment: @whuber By the way, how can I cite this method? Should I just add a footnote with the link to your answer or there is a published paper or book to cite?

Comment: The estimates before the bootstrap are not good ones: the bootstrap is what gives you a decent sense of the uncertainty.  I am not aware of any publication of this, so YMMV.  You can always cite posts here on CV by clicking the `cite` link beneath the post.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!