# How to propagate errors from two sources

Tags: error, measurement-error, error-propagation

Suppose I performed 10 measurements, and have the dataset:

```
17.39 +/- 0.05
17.47 +/- 0.04
17.49 +/- 0.05
17.56 +/- 0.05
17.43 +/- 0.05
17.54 +/- 0.05
17.43 +/- 0.05
17.41 +/- 0.05
17.43 +/- 0.05
17.44 +/- 0.05
```

What is the error on the mean? The standard deviation of the measurements is `0.0528`. But this ignores the individual errors on the measurements. If I propagated these errors, I would get `0.049`. In an ideal world, would I expect these two values to match? Or do I have to combine them, somehow?

Comment: The standard deviation of the measurements automatically incorporates their individual errors.  Think about it: suppose your dataset consisted of ten measurements *of the very same subject.*  Then its standard deviation would estimate the measurement error alone.  A basic statistical relationship -- essentially the Pythagorean Theorem -- guarantees that the measurement error is also incorporated even when your measurements are of different subjects, *provided the measurement is is uncorrelated with the variation among the subjects* (which is usually obviously the case).

Comment: BTW, when the measurement errors themselves vary appreciably, you can exploit that.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/454120 -- which is the very question you have in that general setting.